# Send XML file to FTP/HTTPS server

Tags: android, xml, https, ftp, server

I create small tracking app which get coordinates write them to xml file and then send this file with that data to ftp server. I am using function "SendFileGPS" to send that file but apk all the time crashes and it doesn't work. This function is using additional library common net 1.4 and it is quite strange because all the time when I start Android Studio I must download this library from web by Android Studio. And I got some additional questions.

I was thinking that maybe not only this function is a problem, how should look this server I mean how proper this server to get file from this app?

There is a another way to send this file without using additional libs ?

How it should look if I want send this file to another type of server (HTTPS)?

```
  public void SendFileGPS()
{
    FTPClient mFTP = new FTPClient();
    try {
        // Connect to FTP Server
        mFTP.connect("here I put adress IP");
    mFTP.login("here I put login", "here I put pass");
    mFTP.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    mFTP.enterLocalPassiveMode();

    // Prepare file to be uploaded to FTP Server
    File file = new File("/path/to/MyXmlFileName.xml");
    FileInputStream ifile = new FileInputStream(file);

    // Upload file to FTP Server
    mFTP.storeFile("filetotranfer",ifile);
    mFTP.disconnect();
} catch (SocketException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: If your app crashes you will have exceptions or errors mentioned in the logcat. Please post them here.